# Perl alternative to Cwd::abs_path for symbolic links

Tags: perl, symlink, absolute-path

My Perl app receives relative paths to files and arguments and then converts them to absolute paths.  I had been using `Cwd::abs_path($fileName)` just fine, but now I need to support symbolic links and I find that abs_path will give me the absolute path to the original file.

What I need is an alternative to `Cwd::abs_path` that when given a relative path to a symlink will convert it to an absolute path to that same symlink.  Any recommendations?

Example:

```
/originals/myfile1
/links/myfile1link -> /originals/myfile1

> cd /links
> perl converter.pl /myfile1link
> output: /links/myfile1link
```

Comment: I'm suspecting File::Spec->rel2abs is what I was looking for all along :) I checked the docs, but didn't see anything for either function indicating how they handle symlinks.  Did I miss something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`File::Spec->rel2abs` does not do any system checks, so it won't resolve symlinks.